# (Blazor) ¿Cómo capturo los EventCallbacks de un Componente renderizado con RenderFragment?

Tags: javascript, html, c#, css, blazor

estoy renderizarando un componente, que no se lo que és ni los eventos que tiene con RenderFragment y debo capturar los EventCallbacks para cuando el Usuario lo modifique poder modificar mis datos...

¿Alguien podría darme una idea de como hacerlo?

He intentado añadirle Listeners con Javascript (Interop)pero resulta que los Listeners son para un evento en concreto y yo no se que eventos tiene mi componente

Muchas gracias

Comment: No se entiende el problema, porque quieres todos los eventos si ni siquiera conoces los eventos que tiene?? en cualquier caso debes agregar el código del RenderFragment

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Quiero capturarlos para hacer documentación dinamica de componentes